# How to convert a list of temperatures in Fahrenheit degrees to equivalent Celsius degrees in python?

Tags: python, list

What can be done so that this entire list gets converted into Celsius. Here is what I have tried.
Would appreciate the help.

```
fah = [89.8, 67.0, 92, 99]
count = 0
cen = []
while count != len(fah):
    lst = [x for x in fah]
    cen = ((fah - 32) * 5 / 9)

print(cen)
```

I have got one error which is:
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: It runs forever because the count never changes. (Problem 1). You want cen to be a list but you have made it a single variable (Problem 2). You are not certain how to convert the list and are doing through both a while loop and through list comprehension. (Problem 3).

Comment: I guess I need to learn so much more. Thank you @rajah9 for pointing out the mistakes. Will definitely keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on your approach:

```
fah = [89.8, 67.0, 92, 99]

cen = []
for f in fah:
    c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9
    cen.append(c)

print(cen)
```

Or using a comprehension:

```
cen = [(f - 32) * 5 / 9 for f in fah]
```

Comment: Well I would go with the first one. I didn't know we can add a formula at the beginning in list comprehension. Thank you for the prompt response @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have copied and pasted a large amount of this code as you are trying to iterate through Fahrenheit two times (although one is inside a while loop, so technically 5 times...)

There are a lot of issues with simple things in your code here, you should look at some Python tutorials to help you understand the basics.

However this is how this task could be done Pythonically:

```
fah = [89.8, 67.0, 92, 99]
cen = []
# go through all of the temperatures in fah
for f in fah:
    # for each temp in fah, perform formula and add to cen
    cen.append((f-32)*(5/9))

print(cen)
```

Please try to understand code before using it or you will not learn.

Comment: This code is not copied and pasted at all. I am very new to python programming and I feel mistakes are the proof that you are trying. I have been going through the python tutorials as well. Would definitely try to understand the code from now @Jeremy Savage

Answer (score 0):

Here you can simply use for loop to iterate in fah list and then create a variable ce to convert each element of fah list into celsius degrees and then you can append it into cen list.

```
fah = [89.8, 67.0, 92, 99]
count = 0
cen = []
for i in fah:
    ce = ((i - 32) * 5 / 9)
    cen.append(round(ce,2))

print(cen)
```

[image: Screenshot of code and output]

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of decimals in your "celsius values", you could try this:

```
fah = [89.8, 67.0, 92, 99]
cen = []
for f in fah:
    c = round((f - 32) * 5 / 9,1)
    cen.append(c)
print(cen)
```

The ",1" means 1 decimal.
You can use another number, to your demands.

Comment: Nice approach